# SUBSELECT contains an error - but sql statement continues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following example code:

```
create table #tempmembers (
    memberid int
)

update Members set 
Member_EMail = NULL
where Member_ID in (select member_id from #tempmembers)
```

The subselect contains an error, since `#tempmembes` does not contain a column named `member_id`, but the sql statements run WITHOUT any errors and update no rows.

If I then add just ONE row to `#tempmembers`:

```
create table #tempmembers (
    memberid int
)
insert into #tempmembers select 1

update Members set 
Member_EMail = NULL
where Member_ID in (select member_id from #tempmembers)
```

it still runs without any errors - but this time ALL records in Members will be affected.

Why does the SQL statement not fail completely? And if the failing subselect is evaluated to NULL - should updating all rows in `Members` not only occur if it had been:

```
update Members set 
Member_EMail = NULL
where Member_ID not in (select member_id from #tempmembers)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inheriting `member_id` from the *outer* query so is equivalent to:

```
   ...
   (select Members.member_id from #tempmembers)
```

This will fail as expected:

```
   ...
   (select #tempmembers.member_id from #tempmembers)
```

Comment: Super :S

Why does it do that? Is it MS trying to be nice and let us get away with not prefixing the coloumns - and then opening up for this to happen?

Comment: It can be a gotcha, best to always qualify in a sub-query; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050.aspx

Comment: That is because in this case column name is unique inside of full query so no errors was raised. Question why outer query does need to return its own column? I am not sure but maybe there is an example where you really need in such logic. MS SQL decided that it is such kind of query.